# Python yum module unable to scan for obsolete patches

Tags: python, centos, yum

I am using the yum check-update command in centos to get an update list and also to show obsolete packages.
    Below is the centos command to get the update list, and you can see a list below.

```
[root@CentOS7-G2-3 ~]# yum check-update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirrors.xmission.com
* extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
* updates: mirror.web-ster.com
Obsoleting Packages
python-gobject-base.x86_64  3.22.0-1.el7_4.1    updates  
pygobject3-base.x86_64  3.14.0-3.el7        @anaconda
rdma-core.i686          13-7.el7        base     
rdma.noarch         7.3_4.7_rc2-6.el7_3 @updates 
rdma-core.x86_64        13-7.el7        base     
rdma.noarch         7.3_4.7_rc2-6.el7_3 @updates
```

But when I run the python scripts below, it is not showing any obsolete packages. 
    Can you see why it is not showing obsolete packages? 
    Is there any way to get that obsolete package list?
    The python code below was not able to scan the obsolete patches for centos.

```
import yum
from distutils import version
yumObj = yum.YumBase()
YUM_VER = version.StrictVersion(yum.__version__)
YUM_MAJOR = YUM_VER.version[0]
if YUM_MAJOR == 2:
    yumObj.doTsSetup()
    yumObj.doRepoSetup()
    yumObj.doRepoSetup()
updates = yumObj.doPackageLists('updates').updates
print "updates:"+str(updates)
```

output of executing script given  below:

```
[root@CentOS7-G2-3 ~]# python
 Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  4 2017, 00:39:18) 
 [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-16)] on linux2
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> import yum
 >>> yumObj = yum.YumBase()
 >>> from distutils import version
 >>> YUM_VER = version.StrictVersion(yum.__version__)
 >>> YUM_VER
 StrictVersion ('3.4.3')
 >>> YUM_MAJOR = YUM_VER.version[0]
 >>> YUM_MAJOR
 3
 >>> updates = yumObj.doPackageLists('updates').updates
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
 Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
  * base: mirrors.xmission.com
  * extras: linux.mirrors.es.net
  * updates: mirror.web-ster.com
 >>> print "updates:"+str(updates)
 updates:[]
 >>>
```

Comment: Please give a proper error description! What do you expect the code to do? What did you observe instead? What did you do to diagnose the problem already?

Comment: Hi @KlausD.
I am using yum check-update command in the centos to get update list and also give obsolete packages.

But when i run above mention python scripts, it is not showing obsolete packages. and why it is not showing obsolete packages?

Is there any way to get those obsolete packages?

Comment: Be more detailed and add the information to your question by editing it. Only a good question leads to good answers.

Comment: @KlausD. actually am new to this community.I kept information in detailed.
Can you please help me.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. did you find any root cause?